# Open Graph - XMLNS Required? 

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph

I will be using Open Graph Meta on my site for sharing with Facebook. I am a bit confused though. For the og tags to work it must have the following: `xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#"` Correct?

So it comes down to two questions:

1. Must I have the xmlns?
2. Will it work properly if using HTML5 doctype?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You don't have to use this xmlns syntax. You can use HTML5's prefix:

```
<head prefix='og: http://ogp.me/ns#'>
```

Anyway, this is really just a short hand instead of having the whole namespace in each property.

eg:

```
<head prefix='og: http://ogp.me/ns#'>
    <title>Dom Perignon 1993</title>
    <meta property='og:site_name' content='Wine Site' />
    ...
```

is semantically the same as

```
<head>
    <title>Dom Perignon 1993</title>
    <meta property='http://ogp.me/ns#site_name' content='Wine Site' />
    ...
```